# Django forms out as UL and not DIV

Tags: django, django-forms

Just upgraded my Django app from version 3.2 to version 4.1.

When I now render a form with multiple choices it renders each item as a div and not li.

Sample code as follows:

```
from django import forms
CHOICES = []
for i in range(1, 20):
    CHOICES.append((str(i),str(i)))

class ChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=CHOICES)

form = ChoicesForm()

print(form)
```

The output(shortened) of the print(form) is

```html
<tr>
    <th><label>Choices:</label></th>
    <td>

      <div id="id_choices"><div>
    <label for="id_choices_0"><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="1" id="id_choices_0">
 1</label>

</div><div>
    <label for="id_choices_1"><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="2" id="id_choices_1">
 2</label>

</div><div>
    <label for="id_choices_2"><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="3" id="id_choices_2">
 3</label>

</div><div>
    <label for="id_choices_3"><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="4" id="id_choices_3">
 4</label>
```

But what I was getting in my earlier code was

```html
<tr><th><label>Choices:</label></th><td><ul id="id_choices">
    <li><label for="id_choices_0"><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="1" id="id_choices_0">
 1</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_choices_1"><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="2" id="id_choices_1">
 2</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_choices_2"><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="3" id="id_choices_2">
 3</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_choices_3"><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="4" id="id_choices_3">
 4</label>
```

I can't find any reference to why this would change. Nor can I figure out how to create my form output as a list and not

Is this expected or is there something else I am missing ?

What I ultimately want to achieve is to format the output as rows of items and not a column as the div would create.

Answer (score 0):

Found a reference in the Django documentation that explains why this is happening.  It's a change in CheckboxSelectMultiple() since version 4.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple.  There is an explanation on how to loop over the individual checkboxes so I guess I could do that.  Will need to look at HTML and see if there is a way to make the div statements render horizontally rather than vertically.